# Adding Values to section in numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 1D array in numpy, and I want to add a certain value to part of the array.

For example, if the array is:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to add the value 7 to 2nd and 3rd columns to get:

```
a = [1, 2, 10, 11, 5]
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `a[2] += 7` and `a[3] += 7`?

Comment: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[2] = a[2] + 7 a[3]=a[3]+7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [index the array with another array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) containing the indices:

```
a[[2,3]] += 7
```

Answer (score 4):

If your columns have some pattern, like in this specific case, they are contiguous, then you can use fancy indexing:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a[2:4] += 7
```

Note here `2:4` means "from column 2(included) to column 4(excluded)", thus it's column 2 and 3.